# Menu xml in MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, menu

I'm going crazy! I have this source but why it goes an error?

This is the Menu.xml for MainActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <group android:id="@+id/group1">
        <item android:id="@+id/item1" android:title="X"></item>
        <item android:id="@+id/item2" android:title="Y"></item>
        <item android:id="@+id/item3" android:title="Z"></item>
        <item android:id="@+id/item4" android:title="Share"></item>
</group>
</menu>
```

And this is the Java File

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item1:
                CODE
                }
            return true;
            case R.id.item2:
CODE
            return true;
            case R.id.item3:
CODE
                return true;
            case R.id.item4:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                intent.setType("text/plain");

                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hXXX");

                intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Check out this site!");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "SHARE"));
                return true;
            default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Why give me an error in this line: case R.id.item4: The error is Multiple markers at this line
    - item4 cannot be resolved or is 
     not a field
    - item4 cannot be resolved or is 
     not a field

Comment: maybe bacause it does not exist

Comment: But in xml Menu is there! Do not you see?

Comment: if its really there u think, then just Clean and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your Menu.xml file is saved in 'res/menu/Menu.xml'. If so, try:

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.Menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Otherwise it may be in a different folder, so if your Menu.xml file is in your layout folder (ie 'res/layout/Menu.xml', try:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.Menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just clean your project. The error shall
 be gone.